# Best way to avoid SQL injection on MSSQL Server from C# code using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to avoid SQL injection on MSSQL Server from C# code using Linq?

Should you use a function to strip of security issues or is it handled by the framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Errr, you *cant* SQL inject using LINQ. Behind the scenes LINQ to SQL converts values into a parameterized query.

So yes it is handled by the framework.

Comment: Technically speaking you can still have SQL injection issues if you use the ExecuteCommand or call stored procedures that use sp_execute and combine string input together without proper encoding.